# Select particular fields from Immutable List

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var list = [{id:1,name:'logan',color:'red'},{id:2,name:'paul', color:'green'}];
```

I want to get an array of objects that contains the name and color of each one.
I tried the following but im getting an array of undefined:

```
var array = list.map(item => {name: item.name, color: item.color});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually generates a syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

When using the arrow syntax to return an object literal, you must wrap the object in parentheses, `({})`, to differentiate it from a function body.

```js
var list = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'logan',
  color: 'red'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'paul',
  color: 'green'
}];

var array = list.map(item => ({
  name: item.name,
  color: item.color
}));

console.log(array);
```

<sub>See [Arrow Functions: Advanced Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_Syntax) on MDN</sub>